# Generate .h and .cpp from .ui file

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer, qt3

Suppose I have the file **about.ui**.
How can I make the **"about.h"** and the **"about.cpp"** from my **.ui** file?  I have to create a **.moc** file too?
How can I *compile* this after the creaton to see if all ocurred correctly?

Answer (score 9):

If automatic generation does not work (like in my case) you can use uic to generate the header file manually. `uic file.ui > file.h`

Comment: Sounds like your .ui file is not listed in your .pro file or you didn't re-run qmake.

Comment: Or maybe just QtCreator sucks, doesn't it?

Answer (score 6):

You don't.
The about.ui  generates a ui_about.h which you include in your own about.h

You then create you own class deriving from this class

```
class about :   public QDialog, public Ui::about
{
    Q_OBJECT;
....
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Short answer:

In QtCreator there are two ways of create a form from windows assistant: 
-  **Qt Designer Form Class** 
-  **QtDesigner Form**

you must create a new "**Qt Designer Form Class**" instead of "**Qt Designer Form**", because you choose **"Qt Designer Form"**  qt creator doesn't create the .h and .cpp from .ui file:

Long Answer:

When you create "QTCreator Form" only create .ui  file this is useful if you already have an existing class for the UI business logic and you want rebuilt user interface but keep business logic, you can  call buttom or components with same name and interchange  ui.

Comment: If I use QtCreator to create a class, then will it create myClass.ui, ui_myClass.h, MyClass.h, and MyClass.cpp files?  I'm asking because I have a otherClass.ui file that I'd like to create a class with otherClass.h and otherClass.cpp.  Previously, I did such a thing, and I think I used QtCreator.  However, I can't recall now how I generated the MyClass.h and MyClass.cpp files from the .ui file.

Answer (score 2):

QMake (actually uic) will automatically generate a `ui_about.h` file that you can use to make about.cpp (just make sure to get the .pro file right). Here's a [tutorial](http://pepper.troll.no/s60prereleases/doc/designer-using-a-ui-file.html)

You might want to use the lastest Qt (4.6) too btw.

Comment: Link is dead. This is why you're supposed to quote tutorials here, while giving them credits.

Answer (score 1):

IN VS2008 Follow this step
Go to Form Files->Add->Class->Qt4Classes->Q4GuiClass->Add , then
Fill the class name and click on Finish.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using qt creator in windows, just right click your project and click execute qmake, then it will generate a `ui_xxx.h` and you can add `#include ui_xxx.h` in your file.