# Replace current QWidget to another QWidget in QMainWindow

Tags: c++, qt4

I have some QWidget class which ui files are separate from QMainWindow ui file.

how to add or replace current QWidet which is glued to QMainWindow into other QWidget from different class and ui files on the same QMainWindow ?

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question. I understand 2 different issues here:
1) Loading a custom widget headers to your interface
2) Add/Replace a widget upon an action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are currently displaying one widget and upon an action, you want to hide that widget and display another one in its place.

If this is correct, you might want to look at [QStackedLayout](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstackedlayout.html).

Comment: Nice interpretation skills.

Answer (score 1):

Add your widget headers (note that you have to [generate the headers from ui and inherit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948185/generate-h-and-cpp-from-ui-file)) into promoted widgets in your QMainWindow.ui.

Then, You just have to insert a QWidget,QFrame, ... depending on the base class of your 
widget, and right click on it and select your custom widget from Promote to.. Submenu.

[Heres a link to QT manual](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-custom-widgets.html)