# Replacing QWidgets

Tags: qwidget

I have found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15870739/2756827) but the solution does not resolve my doubt.

I have a `QDialog` with different items, among them a pointer to a `QWidget`. This is adequately integrated in the dialog. I would like to know if I can replace the `QWidget` in the same location. I do not want to hide it, I want to delete the current widget to replace it with the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current approach that I took:

I used a pointer to my current widget (`m_pCurrentWdgt`). I were using the widget inside of a simple layout (few elements), hence I could control the position of the widget manually. Otherwise I would use a additional *support layout* (`m_pLayoutWidget`) to place the widget where I want. The replacement worked as follows: When I want to replace the current widget by a new one (`pWidget`) I delete the current widget from the *support layout* and insert the new one in the previous position (e.g. N_WIDGET).

```
void MyDialog::replaceWidget(QWidget *pWidget) {
     this->m_pLayoutWidget->removeWidget(m_pCurrentWidget);
     delete m_pCurrentWidget;
     m_pCurrentWidget = pWidget;
     this->insertWidget(N_WIDGET, m_CurrentWidget);
}
```

I would like to avoid using Layout here, but at least it worked for me.