# Qt5 User Interface Compiler: -i option not available

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, uic

I created a .ui file (myform.ui) using QtDesigner and I would like to create the corresponding header (myform.h) and implementation (myform.cpp) file.

Now I can create the header file (myform.h) with the following command on Linux:

```
uic mainwindow.ui -o mainwindow.h
```

An older answer on StackExchange ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33935573/10335590%22here%22)) suggested using the following command to create the implementation file (myform.cpp):

```
uic -i mainwindow.h -o mainwindow.cpp mainwindow.ui
```

However, the command option -i doesn't seem to be supported by uic, I get the error message "unknown option -i".

Does anyone know how I can automatically generate the .cpp file from the .h and .ui file?

uic Version is 5.9.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only header files need to be generated, all the code (which is `setupUi()` and `retranslateUi()`) is inside the header generated by uic.