# how to convert .ui fully into c++ header and source file

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, uic

I created something with the Qt Creator Design-Tool.
By doing so I endet up with a `.ui`, a `.h` and two `.cpp` (`mainwindow.cpp` and `main.cpp`) files containing the following:

`mainwindow.ui`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>819</width>
    <height>634</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>580</width>
    <height>400</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout" rowstretch="1,4,4,0" columnstretch="2,0" rowminimumheight="1,1,10,1" columnminimumwidth="1,1">
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="verticalSpacing">
     <number>6</number>
    </property>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <widget class="QFrame" name="selectColonyFrame">
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>150</width>
        <height>40</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="layoutDirection">
       <enum>Qt::RightToLeft</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QPushButton" name="selectColonyButton">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>80</x>
         <y>0</y>
         <width>150</width>
         <height>40</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>150</width>
         <height>40</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>150</width>
         <height>50</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>11</pointsize>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Andere Kolonie ...</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QFrame" name="currentColonyFrame">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Minimum">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>0</width>
        <height>25</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QLabel" name="currentColonyLabel">
       <property name="geometry">
        <rect>
         <x>10</x>
         <y>10</y>
         <width>301</width>
         <height>16</height>
        </rect>
       </property>
       <property name="minimumSize">
        <size>
         <width>220</width>
         <height>15</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>460</width>
         <height>25</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>10</pointsize>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>Aktuelle Kolonie: Lithium-Stollen 13-A</string>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="1">
     <widget class="QFrame" name="missionControlsFrame">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>8</horstretch>
        <verstretch>8</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>300</width>
        <height>180</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::WinPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
       <item>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="misisonControlsLabel">
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>11</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Missionsablauf</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <layout class="QGridLayout" name="missionControlsGridLayout">
         <property name="leftMargin">
          <number>15</number>
         </property>
         <property name="topMargin">
          <number>20</number>
         </property>
         <property name="rightMargin">
          <number>15</number>
         </property>
         <property name="bottomMargin">
          <number>0</number>
         </property>
         <property name="horizontalSpacing">
          <number>20</number>
         </property>
         <property name="verticalSpacing">
          <number>10</number>
         </property>
         <item row="0" column="0">
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="startButton">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>80</width>
             <height>30</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>130</width>
             <height>50</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>12</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Start</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="0" column="1">
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="abortButton">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>80</width>
             <height>30</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>130</width>
             <height>50</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>12</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="layoutDirection">
            <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Abbruch</string>
           </property>
           <property name="autoDefault">
            <bool>false</bool>
           </property>
           <property name="default">
            <bool>false</bool>
           </property>
           <property name="flat">
            <bool>false</bool>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="1" column="0">
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="singleStepButton">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>80</width>
             <height>30</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>130</width>
             <height>50</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>12</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Einzelschritt</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="1" column="1">
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="autoButton">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>80</width>
             <height>30</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>130</width>
             <height>50</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>12</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="layoutDirection">
            <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Automatik</string>
           </property>
           <property name="autoDefault">
            <bool>false</bool>
           </property>
           <property name="default">
            <bool>false</bool>
           </property>
           <property name="flat">
            <bool>false</bool>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="2" column="1">
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="pauseButton">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>80</width>
             <height>30</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>130</width>
             <height>50</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>12</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="layoutDirection">
            <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>Anhalten</string>
           </property>
           <property name="autoDefault">
            <bool>false</bool>
           </property>
           <property name="default">
            <bool>false</bool>
           </property>
           <property name="flat">
            <bool>false</bool>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1" rowspan="2">
     <widget class="QFrame" name="botControlsFrame">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
        <horstretch>4</horstretch>
        <verstretch>4</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>160</width>
        <height>120</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>320</width>
        <height>240</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::WinPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2" rowstretch="0,2,1,1">
       <item row="1" column="0" rowspan="3">
        <layout class="QGridLayout" name="botControlsGridLayout" rowstretch="0,0,0" columnstretch="0,0,0">
         <property name="sizeConstraint">
          <enum>QLayout::SetMinimumSize</enum>
         </property>
         <item row="2" column="1">
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="downButton">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>30</width>
             <height>30</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>50</width>
             <height>50</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="layoutDirection">
            <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
           <property name="icon">
            <iconset resource="grafics.qrc">
             <normaloff>:/grafics/grafics/pfeile/pfeil_unten.tga</normaloff>:/grafics/grafics/pfeile/pfeil_unten.tga</iconset>
           </property>
           <property name="iconSize">
            <size>
             <width>50</width>
             <height>50</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="0" column="1">
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="upButton">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>30</width>
             <height>30</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>50</width>
             <height>50</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeIncrement">
            <size>
             <width>0</width>
             <height>0</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
           <property name="icon">
            <iconset resource="grafics.qrc">
             <normaloff>:/grafics/grafics/pfeile/pfeil_oben.tga</normaloff>:/grafics/grafics/pfeile/pfeil_oben.tga</iconset>
           </property>
           <property name="iconSize">
            <size>
             <width>50</width>
             <height>50</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="1" column="1">
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="waitButton">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>30</width>
             <height>30</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>50</width>
             <height>50</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <family>MS Shell Dlg 2</family>
             <pointsize>15</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
            <enum>Qt::DefaultContextMenu</enum>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>W</string>
           </property>
           <property name="icon">
            <iconset theme="&amp;#9664">
             <normaloff>.</normaloff>.</iconset>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="1" column="0">
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="leftButton">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>30</width>
             <height>30</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>50</width>
             <height>50</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
           <property name="icon">
            <iconset resource="grafics.qrc">
             <normaloff>:/grafics/grafics/pfeile/pfeil_links.tga</normaloff>:/grafics/grafics/pfeile/pfeil_links.tga</iconset>
           </property>
           <property name="iconSize">
            <size>
             <width>50</width>
             <height>50</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="0" column="2">
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="deleteButton">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>30</width>
             <height>30</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>50</width>
             <height>50</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="font">
            <font>
             <pointsize>15</pointsize>
            </font>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string>&lt;</string>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
         <item row="1" column="2">
          <widget class="QPushButton" name="rightButton">
           <property name="minimumSize">
            <size>
             <width>30</width>
             <height>30</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="maximumSize">
            <size>
             <width>50</width>
             <height>50</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="sizeIncrement">
            <size>
             <width>0</width>
             <height>0</height>
            </size>
           </property>
           <property name="text">
            <string/>
           </property>
           <property name="icon">
            <iconset resource="grafics.qrc">
             <normaloff>:/grafics/grafics/pfeile/pfeil_rechts.tga</normaloff>:/grafics/grafics/pfeile/pfeil_rechts.tga</iconset>
           </property>
           <property name="iconSize">
            <size>
             <width>50</width>
             <height>50</height>
            </size>
           </property>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="0" colspan="2">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="botControlsLabel">
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>11</pointsize>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Programmieren</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="1">
        <widget class="QComboBox" name="repeatDropdown">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>80</width>
           <height>30</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>130</width>
           <height>50</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="font">
          <font>
           <pointsize>15</pointsize>
           <weight>75</weight>
           <italic>false</italic>
           <bold>true</bold>
          </font>
         </property>
         <property name="focusPolicy">
          <enum>Qt::WheelFocus</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="layoutDirection">
          <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="currentText">
          <string>1</string>
         </property>
         <property name="insertPolicy">
          <enum>QComboBox::NoInsert</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frame">
          <bool>true</bool>
         </property>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>1</string>
          </property>
         </item>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>2</string>
          </property>
         </item>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>3</string>
          </property>
         </item>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>4</string>
          </property>
         </item>
         <item>
          <property name="text">
           <string>5</string>
          </property>
         </item>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="2" column="1">
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_6">
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="3" column="1">
        <widget class="QFrame" name="botCommandFrame">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>100</width>
           <height>80</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>130</width>
           <height>16777215</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <widget class="QTextEdit" name="botCommandTextEdit">
          <property name="geometry">
           <rect>
            <x>0</x>
            <y>16</y>
            <width>108</width>
            <height>50</height>
           </rect>
          </property>
          <property name="sizePolicy">
           <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
            <horstretch>130</horstretch>
            <verstretch>50</verstretch>
           </sizepolicy>
          </property>
          <property name="minimumSize">
           <size>
            <width>80</width>
            <height>30</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="maximumSize">
           <size>
            <width>130</width>
            <height>50</height>
           </size>
          </property>
          <property name="font">
           <font>
            <pointsize>15</pointsize>
           </font>
          </property>
          <property name="verticalScrollBarPolicy">
           <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="horizontalScrollBarPolicy">
           <enum>Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="lineWrapMode">
           <enum>QTextEdit::NoWrap</enum>
          </property>
          <property name="readOnly">
           <bool>true</bool>
          </property>
          <property name="placeholderText">
           <string>Textfeld</string>
          </property>
         </widget>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0" rowspan="3">
     <widget class="QFrame" name="mapFrame">
      <property name="sizePolicy">
       <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="MinimumExpanding">
        <horstretch>0</horstretch>
        <verstretch>0</verstretch>
       </sizepolicy>
      </property>
      <property name="minimumSize">
       <size>
        <width>120</width>
        <height>120</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_6">
       <property name="spacing">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <item row="0" column="0">
        <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="MinimumExpanding">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>0</width>
           <height>0</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::Box</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Umgebungskarte</string>
         </property>
         <property name="alignment">
          <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="0" column="1">
        <widget class="QScrollBar" name="verticalScrollBar">
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item row="1" column="0">
        <widget class="QScrollBar" name="horizontalScrollBar">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="Fixed">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="orientation">
          <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>819</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources>
  <include location="grafics.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

`mainwindow.h`:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_upButton_clicked();

    void on_rightButton_clicked();

    void on_downButton_clicked();

    void on_leftButton_clicked();

    void on_waitButton_clicked();

    void on_deleteButton_clicked();

    void on_selectColonyButton_clicked();

    void on_startButton_clicked();

    void on_abortButton_clicked();

    void on_singleStepButton_clicked();

    void on_autoButton_clicked();

    void on_pauseButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

`mainwindow.cpp`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "QMessageBox"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_upButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "button", "up");
}

void MainWindow::on_rightButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "button", "right");
}

void MainWindow::on_downButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "button", "down");
}

void MainWindow::on_leftButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "button", "left");
}

void MainWindow::on_waitButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "button", "wait");
}

void MainWindow::on_deleteButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "button", "delete");
}

void MainWindow::on_selectColonyButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "button", ui->selectColonyButton->text());
}

void MainWindow::on_startButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "button", ui->startButton->text());
}

void MainWindow::on_abortButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "button", ui->abortButton->text());
}

void MainWindow::on_singleStepButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "button", ui->singleStepButton->text());
}

void MainWindow::on_autoButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "button", ui->autoButton->text());
}

void MainWindow::on_pauseButton_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "button", ui->pauseButton->text());
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Now I what I'd like to have is a `.cpp` file containing not only the signals and slot I created manually, but everything. Every layout I added with the designer, every label, every button. And as far as I know there is a way to achieve exactly that: `qmake`or `uic`

The problem now is: how do I actually use one of those?

I've tried using `uic` via command prompt by opening the folder all those files are in and executing this: `uic -o mainwindow.h mainwindow.ui`
(googled a bit and found that)

But the error I got was something like this: either the "uic" command written wrongly or couldn't be found. (tried to translate it from my language)

Any ideas on how to fix the problem or any different ideas on how to achieve what I need?

Comment: What OS are you using? What compiler are you using?

Comment: How did you install qt?

Comment: @thomas I downloaded `qt-unified-windows-x86-3.1.1-online.exe` and when it came to chosing the verison of qt and stuff I chose "Qt 5.12.6" -> "MSVC 2017 64-bit" and "Qt 5.12.6" -> "MinGW 7.3.0 64-bit"

Comment: If you are on Windows, make sure to use the command prompt from your desired Qt kit (i.e. start menu -> Qt -> version -> kit -> command prompt). `uic` should be available there.

Comment: Sorry to answer so late, but I went to bed. 
So I got my header file now, but the to get the .cpp file I'm supposed to use this: `uic -i headerfile.h -o newName.cpp uiFile.ui`, but if I use this it says: `uic: Unknown option 'i'.`
Ideas?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708498/qt5-user-interface-compiler-i-option-not-available) the implementation is inside the already created header file. I've got 2 functions: `void setupUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)` and `void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *MainWindow)`. Are those the funcitons belonging into a `.cpp`? If so, then there is not much left for the header :/
Since I can't seem to find a con-/destructor and there are several `new` calls: how are they destroyed after?

Answer (score 0):

Use qmake, here's the link with all basic explanations:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-tutorial.html

For .ui files, you add them to the .pro file like this:

```
FORMS += foo.ui
```

Comment: I've tried to work my way through, but I've got the same problem as I did with `uic`. I think I've got something wrong with my `PATH` variables. What  exact path do I need to add to the `PATH` variables to be able to use `qmake`?
I know that the path to some folders is specific to my pc but I don't know which folder/file exactly must be added to be able to use `qmake`